# CSS continue animation after mouseleave

Tags: javascript, css

Can someone please help me with css animation? Mb I should use js too?
I want to create hover animation left->right but after mouse leave, I want to continue animation left->right not right->left.

Thanks

```css
.button_sliding_bg {
    color: #31302B;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 12px 17px;
    margin: 25px;
    font-family: 'OpenSansBold', sans-serif;
    border: 3px solid #31302B;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #31302B;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.8s;
 transition: all ease 0.8s;
}
.button_sliding_bg:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 100px 0 0 0 #31302B;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button class="button_sliding_bg">
Button
</button>
```

I want something like this:

[image]

Here is the solution:

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'visible';
}, 400);
```

```css
.button_sliding_bg {
    visibility:hidden;
    padding: 12px 17px;
    margin: 25px;
    font-family: 'OpenSansBold', sans-serif;
    border: 3px solid #31302B;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: animate-out 0.5s 1;
   animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.button_sliding_bg:hover {
    animation: animate-in 0.5s 1;
 animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes animate-in {
 0% {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #31302B;
  color:#31302B;
     background: #FFF;
 }
 100% {
  box-shadow: inset 100px 0 0 0 #31302B;
  color:#FFF;
     background: #FFF;
 }
}
@keyframes animate-out {
 0% {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #FFF; 
     background: #31302B;
  color:#FFF;
 }
 100% {
  box-shadow: inset 100px 0 0 0 #FFF; 
     background: #31302B;
  color:#31302B;
 }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" class="button_sliding_bg">
Button
</button>
```

Comment: Please post the code of what you have tried.

Comment: I've just added code that I'm using.

Comment: Do you want this effect on button from your example, or on text (to make 'transparent text'), exactly as on .gif?

Comment: I need it form <li><a>About Us</a></li> :)

Comment: So can someone help me with it? :) I've got like -4 for this question and nobody know the solution :( sad.

Comment: @kironet, not sure why question is downvoted, it is a good question, but, i am afraid that desired effect is pretty complex (though it looks so simple), and it is very hard to find: 1) only CSS solution (you will have to use some js, i am almost sure) 2) cross browser solution...Check 'CSS masking', 'background clip:text', 'mix-blend-mode'... maybe you will find something... E.g. this could help, maybe: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/12/experiments-with-background-clip-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont mind that it runs the first when the page loads, you can use CSS3's `animation` properties to get what you're trying to achieve. The trick is the combination of changing the `animation-name` on hover and the use of [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to persist the changes made. Do keep in mind that CSS3's animation is considered "experimental", however, it has [almost complete coverage](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) on the latest browser versions.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sx4f129q/2/)**

**CSS**

```
.button_sliding_bg {
    padding: 12px 17px;
    margin: 25px;
    font-family: 'OpenSansBold', sans-serif;
    border: 3px solid #31302B;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation-name: animate-out;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-repeat-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.button_sliding_bg:hover {
    animation-name: animate-in;
}

@keyframes animate-in {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #31302B;
        color:#31302B;
        background: #FFF;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 100px 0 0 0 #31302B;
        color:#FFF;
        background: #FFF;
    }
}
@keyframes animate-out {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #FFF; 
        background: #31302B;
        color:#FFF;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 100px 0 0 0 #FFF; 
        background: #31302B;
        color:#31302B;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. So I think I should use javascript for this.