# Text colour fill from left to right using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to animate the text having class `".popUpWord"`. On hover, I would like to do a colour animation with the colour of text changing from left to right.

```
<span class="popUpWord">hello</span>
```

What I would like to do is similar to this one - [Animate text fill from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952222/animate-text-fill-from-left-to-right) , but I want it to be filled in from left to right and **stop**, rather than repeating it.

Is this possible through css please?

Comment: Do you mean a [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient)?

Comment: What I would like to achieve looks similar to how karaoke text is displayed. I don't know whether this can be achieved using gradient

Comment: you mean like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBemaM ...

Comment: @DaniP , similar to that one. However, I would like to show the word 'Text' for example in white first, and then fill it in from left to right with colour.

Comment: And what stops you to try it ??? try change the initial color  or somehting ...

Comment: @DaniP already tried it but I didn't manage that's why I asked.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpEXPz ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add an outer div add `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` when `:hover`

```css
.popUpWord {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 26vmax/.8 Open Sans, Impact;
  background: black;
  display: table;
  color: white;
}

.outPop:hover {
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient( crimson , crimson) white no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 0 100%;
  animation: stripes 2s linear 1 forwards;
}
.outPop:hover .popUpWord{
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

@keyframes stripes {
  to {
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
}

body {
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outPop">
<div class="popUpWord">
  Text
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! This is almost exact effect like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826683/css-continue-animation-after-mouseleave Anyway, is there any chance to get desired effect when mouse is moved from text (on mouseleave)??? So, red background should move further, from left to right, making text white again, gradually?

Comment: @nevermind if we want this effect when mouse leave then we can set it in default itself and remove animation on `:hover`

Comment: No, i wasn't clear obviously, sorry... please check .gif OP posted... Your animation is perfect on hover, now it just should be continued on mouseleave... not sure that it is possible only with CSS...

Comment: We can not control mouse out through css. So we can make this as always animating and on hover we can stop the animation in red text. So after mouse out the animation will start again

Comment: I've been trying to implement it in my website..I think I'm missing something. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYojzZ - I know that in this pen it is not working on hover, but I know the reason for that. What I don't know is why the pink background is being displayed from left to right rather than the text colour.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this years after it was answered. The accepted answer does not work with different background colors as far as I can tell. For example I tried it with a dark grey background and it create a dark box behind the text that I didn't want.

I looked for other solutions and found this one. Basically you have two instances of the same text exactly positioned on top of each other. The text is positioned using css-grid's `justify-content: start` and has `overflow:hidden` on with a width of 0.

On hover, the width of the fill-text div is increased which effectively achieves the same effect: revealing the overlay text from left to right. There is an extra div wrapped around the overlay text that is wide enough to fit the entire width of the text. This prevents the text from jumping down to the next line when the div is increasing in size.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: beige
}

.fill-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.fill-text {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: keep-all;
  width: 0;
  color: red;
  transition: 0.5s width ease-in-out;
}

.text {
  width: 150px;
  color: black;
}

.wrapper:hover .fill-text {
  width: 150px;
  transition: 0.5s width ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fill-text">
    <div class="fill-wrapper">
      My Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    My Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the new feature `background-clip:text`. First, we set our `color` as transparent (this will make our background color visible), then set the background as a gradient with two colors at 50% each (the first color is the one we will transition to, and the second color is the base color). Next, we set our `background-size` to 200% and `background-position` to 100% (this will make visible only our second color). Finally, we add the hover effect with `background-position:0;`

```css
h1{
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 50%, green 50%);
  background-position:100%;
  background-size:200% 100%;
  background-clip:text;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  
  transition: background-position 1s ease;
}
h1:hover{
  background-position:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

background position.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me create this https://codepen.io/danbrellis/pen/dyQmbex